# Reopen Closed Question (reason for closing : Off Topic)

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I posted the following question on Super User : https://superuser.com/questions/537232/issues-with-htaccess-url-re-write

However this is not the original question , the original question seemed application specific and thus was marked as off topic and closed . I did some more experiments to determine where exactly I might be going wrong and now it is clear that it is not related to my application but to apache/htaccess/mod_rewrite thus it being suitable for super user . Please note the current question on the above URL holds no resemblance to the original question (which was down voted and closed) .

I request moderators/users with enough reputation to have a look at the question and reopen if it seems fit .

Comment: **Please** figure out how formatting works. You've now asked around 50 questions on Stack Exchange already, so you should know how to do that. The question in its current form isn't acceptable anywhere, sorry.

Comment: Changed the formatting . Sorry for what was posted earlier .

Answer (score 6):

This question (in either revision) is off topic for Super User as it concerns the building and deployment of your website.

There are three sites where you could post this:

1. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) if you are installing this on your own servers.
2. [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you are installing this on managed servers.

   or possibly:
3. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if you are developer.

However, check each site's FAQ and do a search to see which one would be most appropriate before you post and make sure that your post is properly formatted.